# How to do state-dependent caching in a notebook?

Tags: python, caching, jupyter-notebook, ipython

I have a Jupyter notebook with large intermediate data frames that are computationally intensive to generate. I would like to be able to cache them between sessions. However, I would like to be able to automatically recompute them if one of the steps/variables used to generate the resulting data frames has changed (e.g. new data are filtered data upstream). Is there some way to link a cached variable to any number of "state" variables such that the target variable is recomputed if a change in the "state" has been detected (and loaded from cache is no change is detected)?

#### Related Questions/Answers on SO

- [How to cache in IPython Notebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31255894/how-to-cache-in-ipython-notebook?rq=1), [ipython notebook save variables after closing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32210951/ipython-notebook-save-variables-after-closing?rq=3)

  Answer: Use `%store`

  The cache has to be manually recomputed.
- [How to pickle or store Jupyter (IPython) notebook session for later](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34342155/how-to-pickle-or-store-jupyter-ipython-notebook-session-for-later?rq=3)

  Answer: Use `dill` to dump and load a session

  I do not want to save the entire session because that would be too large. I want to save intermediate values that are difficult to recompute, and recompute the cells that are not so computationally expensive

#### Example of what I'm looking for...

*Consider this a notebook environment, with cells separated by the* `# ---- #` *comments.*

```py
# Initial work, loading datasets and whatnot

df = load_dataset()
df = clean_dataset()

# Some intermediate variables that are used later on...
s1, s2, s3 = compute_intermediate_variables()

# ---- #

# Intensive computation cell

def compute(df, s1, s2, s3): # Defining the expensive computation
    return some_func(df, s1, s2, s3)

... # Hopefully use `compute` in the caching operation...
```

I am looking for a caching function or notebook magic thingy that can cache the result of `compute` and recompute it *only* if a change in `df`, `s1`, `s2`, or `s3` has been detected. Therefore, rerunning the cell repeatedly should be a near-instant operation. Repeatedly opening, running, and then closing the notebook should also not be hindered by this "expensive computation cell" *after* the first time.